# parse rss feed while exclude some text

Tags: php, parsing, dom, xpath

i am trying to parse the user names from an rss feed using php, but for some reason its not working correctly here is my code.

```
$feedDom = new DomDocument();
$feedDom ->load($TURL);
$xPath = new DomXPath($TwitterDom);
$usernames = $xPath->xpath("//author/name']");


echo $usernames;
```

I looked at the rss feed and here is what i am trying to parse, but I would like to exclude the (jimmy), and only parse the user name.

```
<author>
      <name>ilovemyname (jimmy)</name>
</author>
```

Comment: Clearly, `//author/name']` it's a not valid XPath expression. `//author/name` is it.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
$usernames = substr($usernames, 0, strpos($usernames, ' '));
```